# Missing value for user.email in git.config

Tags: git, git-config

I observed that all my commits are logged in by name of administrator.  Tried updating my email address and user name using git config.

```
TTHOMAS10:rpr-mobile administrator$ git config user.name "Sumit Gupta"

rpr-mobile administrator$ git config user.email
"my@email.address"

TTHOMAS10:rpr-mobile administrator$ git status
error: Missing value for 'user.email'
fatal: bad config file line 17 in .git/config
```

Not sure why i am not able to set user name and email for my repository.

Comment: What's the output of `git config user.email`?

Comment: The output is correct email address, but when i run "git status" it says bad config file.  Looks like my change is not committed.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your config file?

Comment: What's on `line 17` of the `.git/config` file in that specific repository?

Comment: I was running short of time so i deleted the repository and created it. Thanks for looking into this @leigh and leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the repository and recreated it to resolve the issue.